# why does this text translate to a url

Tags: url, firefox

error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.4 @NonNull

I put this error I encountered while trying stuff in kotlin and put it in the search box of firefox. It kept translating into the url "http://nonnull/". I want to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User credentials can be encoded into URLs in the form: `https://username:password@hostname/`.

Your string matches that format (with the scheme implied).